# MVC Razor - How to update a multiple rows in a selected column from a dropdown list SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I think the title says it all...
I want to update a whole table with an input filled value into a selected column (selected from a dropdown list) if the value of another column is equal to a selected value (from another dropdown list). Putting all this together seem pretty hard for me...

Like this kind of Query...

`var db = Database.Open("DatabaseX");
var updateCommand = "UPDATE TableX Set SelectedColumn(dropdownlistA) = (InputA) IF ColumnX = Selected Values(dropdownlistB)";`

Sorry for my english

Comment: how does your view/generated markup looks like (only relevant parts please) . do you want to do this on the form submit ?

Comment: I want to do it on submit... And for the view generated markup, I'm not sure about what you're talking about...
Do you speak about this?     
@Html.DropDownList("NoCam", NoCamdropdownlistdata)<br>
<select name="ValuedropdownlistB" width="15">
     <option></option>
     <option value=@Request.Form["ValuedropdownlistB"]>ValueA</option>
  </select>
And 
<input size="10" type="text" name="InputA" value="@InputA" /></p>
It's the first time I try to influence the query from selected source. It's new for me

Comment: Which part are you you having trouble with ? Getting the selected values ? updating db record ? You have to show the specific part where it is not working as expected or you having troubles.

Comment: Getting the selected Value. It's easy to insert a value in a know column according to row.id... But letting chose the column and a if condition by the user is unknown to me. (Stack Overflow has been very helpfull to me even if my questions are bad according to the site and are always downvoted =P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having trouble getting the selected values from the dropdown on form submit, you may try this.

Create a view model with properties for the data for the dropdown and the selected option value.

```
public class CreateUserVm
{
    public int SelectedCam { set; get; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Cams { set; get; }

    public int SelectedCat { set; get; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { set; get; }
}
```

And in your GET action, create an object of this, initialize the collection properties and send tot he view.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var v = new CreateUserVm
    {
        Categories = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = "1", Text = "Photo"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "2", Text = "Video"}
        },
        Cams = new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem {Value = "25", Text = "DSLR"},
            new SelectListItem {Value = "28", Text = "Point and Shoot"}
        }
    };
    return View(v);
}
```

Now your create view should be strongly typed to this CreateUserVm class.

```
@model CreateUserVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(g=>g.SelectedCat, Model.Categories)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(g=>g.SelectedCam, Model.Cams)
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

And in your HttpPost action method, we will use the CreateUserVm object as the parameter so that the posted model will be mapped to it by the default model binder.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CreateUserVm model)
{
  var camId = model.SelectedCam;
  var catId = model.SelectedCat;

  // use camId and catId to update your db.
  // to do  : Save and Redirect
}
```

Comment: Thank you, you're a machine